# Python3 currency abstract class (without the permission to be instantiated directly)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, classes, inheritance

I'm a newbie python developer who *accidentally* studied the concept of
[**Abstract classes**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-classes-in-python/)
and I found it pretty much helpful to implement due to the SOLID principles.

At the very moment of testing and learning the concept, I found out that using a abstract class also as an mix-in class would be a great Idea, so I decided to implement the `__init__` method in the base abstract class.

As I am new to the concept, I don't know if this is a good implementation for making reusable software:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Dependency inversion learning file | By : KhodeNima |
2023/10/25
"""


from decimal import (
    Decimal
)

from abc import (
    ABC,
)

class BaseCurrency(ABC):
    def __init__(self, value_by_dollar : Decimal):
        """The base currency class

        Args:
            - value_by_dollar (Decimal): The value of the currency in Dollar.
        """

        self.__name = self.__class__.__name__
        self.value_by_dollar = value_by_dollar

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name : str):

        if name == "BaseCurrency":
            raise PermissionError("The BaseCurrency class can only be inherited | ( Not instantiated )")
        
        return name

    

class Dirham(BaseCurrency):
    ...


some_decimal_value = Decimal('10.0')
dirham_1 = Dirham(value_by_dollar=some_decimal_value)
```

Comment: Is there some code missing from `Dirham`?  It would be helpful for reviewers to see this implementation (as it clarifies how you intend the base to be extended).  Question size limit is plenty large enough for you to fill that in - thanks!

Comment: Which dollars? USD?

Comment: `dirham_1.name` results in `AttributeError: 'Dirham' object has no attribute '_name'. Did you mean: 'name'?` And `dirham_1.name = "Name"` doesn't do anything. As such your code is just a long-winded way of storing only `value_by_dollar`.

Answer (score 5):

### Constructor

The idea behind Abstract Base Classes is that they can't be instantiated by themselves, only their subclasses can. However, we would still use `__init__` to ensure that attributes of class instances are set properly. In your case, that would be both `_name` and `value_by_dollar`.

If that is all that is needed in a constructor, then subclasses don't even need to provide their own constructor. Calling `__init__` in that case redirects to the base class' implementation. Otherwise, remember to call
super().**init**() to explicitly call the superclass constructor.

Coupling the class name with the instance attribute __name `self.__name = self.__class__.__name__` is a bad practice. There is no reason why they should be coupled - and you're defining a setter so that coupling can fall apart later.

A better idea would be to ask for the currency name in the constructor of the base class. Then, in subclasses, we would call `super().__init__()` by providing a string as the currency name. This enables you to change the `_name` attribute without changing the class names of the subclasses.

Also, a side note: there is a typo when setting `_name` (note the double underscore)!

### Name Property Getter and Setter

Here, you provide a default for both implementations. Note that you haven't defined any of them as `abc.abstractmethod` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)), indicating that subclasses need not override them. Classes inheriting from ABC cannot be instantiated unless all abstract methods or properties are implemented. However, since you provided implementations for all methods, `BaseCurrency` can be instantiated.

In addition the name setter explicitly checks the `_name` attribute of the instance to avoid the setter to be called. This puts a cognitive load on you to change the condition if you ever change the `BaseCurrency` to be called something else.

Thankfully, there is an easy fix for both of these - declare the setter as an abstract method:

```
@name.setter
@abstractmethod
def name(self, name : str):
    pass
```

Since you have an abstract method now, `BaseCurrency` cannot be instantiated. Also, subclasses need to implement their own name setter which eliminates the need to check if the calling class is the base one.

This also means you actually need to provide a body to the `Dirham` class. Usually, empty subclasses of an abstract class tell you either you don't need an abstract class (everything can be done through instantiation) or you are doing too much in the abstract class that should be left to the subclasses. And an abstract class with no abstract methods (that is, without places that need to be filled in for the class to *do something*) is abstract only in name.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ There is no code missing. In the Dirham class, there is an ellipse - the effect would be the same if there was just `pass`. Dirham is a proper subclass, but does not override anything so the body can be left empty. I couldn't comment on the top post yet.

Comment: I apologize for missing that. I have removed my comment.

Comment: Is `...` a synonym for `pass`?  Is that a fairly recent thing?  I'd not heard of it before.

Comment: @TobySpeight `...` is a singleton value similar to `None`. It doesn't do anything by itself, but can be used for various practical purposes. It's been around since 3.5 if I'm not mistaken. On a line by itself it's just an expression that evaluates to itself and does nothing. It can be used in place of `pass`, but I've understood that there's a convention to use `pass` to mean "this intentionally does nothing" and `...` to mean "not implemented".